# R replace NA to empty field(nothing) when write in Excel

Tags: r, excel, na

I want that NA replace empty field. Can you write function. Can in R store empty fields?

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
require(readxl)
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'Russian')
fname <- file.choose()
basetable<- read_xlsx(fname)
result_table<-basetable %>% 
  group_by(`Product`,`Mark`,`Dens.`,`Format`,`Cons`,`Date`,`Company`)%>% 
  summarise(`Sum` = sum(`Weight`),`Count`=sum(`Расход`==0)) 
xlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(result_table), 'file.xlsx', sheetName="Sheet 5", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: `result_table[is.na(result_table)] <- ''` ?

Comment: `write.xlsx` has an argument to achieve this: *showNA a logical value. If set to FALSE, NA values will be left as empty cells.* See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.3/topics/write.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

The function [`xlsx::write.xlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.3/topics/write.xlsx) has the argument `showNA` which is at default set to `TRUE`. This argument controls if NA values are left as is (when TRUE) or if they are left as empty cells (when FALSE).

```
xlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(result_table),
                 'file.xlsx',
                 sheetName = "Sheet 5",
                 append = TRUE,
                 showNA = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that [does not require the rJava package](https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/06/13/reading-Excel-files.html) is the `writexl` package, which by default does not write NA to an output Excel file.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,NA,5),y = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df,"./data/writexl_output.xlsx")
```

...and the results when we open the file in Excel:

[image]